# Replace a column data with data from another column in the same table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table, TABLEA with columns, ID and CAT Name. I would like to run a query that outputs the column CAT with its values replaced in values in the ID column. could someone please help?

ID(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

CAT(leo, toby, oliver, blade, milo)

I want the output to be:
CAT(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: updated my question, not sure how to input tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID as CAT from yourtable
```